# В завершение/В завершении

Tags: орфография

Ув. филологи! Подскажите, как верно?
В завершение процедуры внимание уделяют коже головы и наносят смягчающее масло.

Answer (score 1):

Действительно, это производный предлог со значением цели, Е на конце соответствует направленному В.п. (чтобы завершить процедуру).

Можно добавить, что этот производный предлог следует отличать от сущ. в П.п., например: Все заинтересованы в завершении строительных работ.

Answer (score 1):

### Короткая версия:

Когда речь идёт о **времени**, то *"в течение"*. Когда о **сущности** - *"в течении"*. Соответственно, когда речь идёт о **времени** после чего-то, то *"в завершение"*. Когда о **сущности** (части) - *"в завершении"*.

По сути вопроса: если речь идёт о **части процедуры**, то скорее всего *"в завершении"*.

### Длинная версия:

*"В начале романа Дубровский едет в своё имение, в основной части он влюбляется, а в завершении - бросается под поезд"*. Т.е. у романа есть начало, основная часть и завершение, и в завершении что-то такое содержится. Речь идёт о сущности (части романа).

*"В завершение своего доклада хочу поблагодарить организаторов конференции за отличную работу"*. Т.е. после доклада, когда тот уже закончился, он благодарит организаторов. Речь идёт о времени.

P.S. прошу не придираться к сюжету упомянутого романа. Написал первое, что пришло в голову.

Мне лучше всего запоминается другой аналог - слово *"течение"*.

*"В течении реки есть что-то завораживающее"*. Река течёт, и этот акт течения завораживает.

*"В течении года есть что-то завораживашее"*. Год (время) течёт (проходит), и этот акт течения завораживает.

*"Лодка попала в подводное течение"*. Течение - отдельная сущность (или принимаемый за сущность процесс) в море.

*"В течение года проект был сдан"*. Год сам не течёт! Здесь "в течение" означает "во время".

Answer (score 1):

В завершении, т.к. этап завершения процедуры.

Comment: Пишите, пожалуйста, подробнее. Так чтобы ответт Был понятен тем, кто не не в курсе, почему наличие слова "процедура" здесь существенно.

Answer (score 0):

Производный предлог 'в завершение'

Answer (score 0):

Такое чувство, что предлог как-то схож cо словосочетанием "По завершении". Писать-то, бесспорно, следует через букву е, потому что это производный предлог, образованный от существительного *завершение*.

Comment: Вы совершенно правы, есть еще предлог "по завершении" со значением ВРЕМЕНИ, там используется форма П.п., например:  По завершении работ следует составить акт.Это целый ряд предлогов: по окончании школы, по прибытии на место.

Comment: Разве это не существительное с предлогом ПО в значений 'после '?

Comment: Да, Вы правы, это предлог ПО здесь имеет значение времени, но управляет П.п., а не Д.п., что характерно для этого предлога.

Answer (score 0):

Похоже, что оба варианта допустимы. Если это производный предлог, то да, ***"в завершение"***, тут обсуждать нечего, просто вспомнить, что он образован от ***винительного*** падежа.
А вот если считать, что "завершение" здесь обычное существительное в предложном падеже с предлогом, то, естественно, ***"в завершении"***. Этот случай представляется вполне реальным.
Другими словами, надо определиться, имеет ли здесь "завершение процедуры" временнОе значение (тогда это производный предлог), или это просто фаза процедуры.